# How to find strings in a file using MATLAB

Tags: string, file, matlab

I have a file which contains repeating strings. File is very large so I give a simple example:

```
a    b    c
w    a    g
b    v    f
```

I want to extract `a b` to an array. How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Is there a reason/pattern how the string you want to extract (``a b``) relates to the *repeating* strings in your document?

Comment: so basically, you are looking for a specific string, which would be given as input, in a file. Does [``strfind``](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) do that for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/reading-arbitrary-format-text-files-with-textscan.html). You can split the file by '\n' and then by whitespace with cell2mat.

```
fid = fopen('your_string_file.ext');
input = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
cellmatrix = cell2mat(input{1});


cellmatrix =
     a b c
     d f a
     b v f
```

Then if there is a specific pattern you want you can walk the cellmatrix. Assuming you want the `a b` pattern within a single row you could do the following:

```
pattern = ['a', 'b'];
patindex = 1;
dims = size(cellmatrix);
for i=1:dims(1)
    patindex = 1;
    for j=1:dims(2)
        if strcmp(cellmatrix(i,j), ' ')
            continue
        end
        if strcmp(cellmatrix(i,j), pattern(patindex))
            patindex = patindex+1;
            if patindex > length(pattern)
                FOUND... store location/do what you want
                patindex = 1;
            end
        else
            patindex = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

You can change your check to find whatever pattern you want from the matrix.

This assumes your file will fit into memory -- if it's too large to fit in half your memory you'll need to do something much trickier with incremental passes and file writing.

Comment: But this just reads the file - I think @newzad wanted to find a string in that file.

Comment: Well he didn't specify the pattern he wanted so I interpreted it as he wanted to convert the text to arrays. I'll add how to grab a pattern from this read.

Comment: The for-loop is a kind of overkill here. "strcmp" can work already natively on cellarrays.

Comment: True if he wants to check for a single character/simple pattern. But since he didn't really specify the pattern very well I don't think this is really overkill.

Answer (score 2):

After you have the cellmatrix from the answer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549797/2084944)!, you can use strcmp to create a true/falls matrix regarding you pattern:

```
strcmp(cellmatrix,'a')
```

If your file is very large, so it doesnt fit into you memory, try to read the file line-by-line using fgets:

```
fid = fopen('VERYBIGFILE');
tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgets(fid);
    %% DO SOME STUF WITH THE LINE
end
fclose(fid);
```